# Cant successfully Save a SecretKey as a String

Tags: java, encryption, secret-key

I'm trying to save a key in an XML file for later decryption of a encrypted string, the software can encrypt and return me at the "Encrypt()" method, but returns error when trying to use the "Decrypt()" method

Code

```
 private static Cipher ecipher;
private static Cipher dcipher;

public static String[] encrypt(String str) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    String Key, res;
    SecretKey key;
    String[] Return = new String[2];

    key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
    ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");
    byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

    enc = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(enc);
    res = new String(enc);

    //Returning values 0 = Encrypted String 1 = Key For Storage in XML
    Return[0] = res;
    byte[] keyBytes = key.getEncoded(); 
    Key = new String(keyBytes,"UTF8");
    Return[1] = Key;

    return Return;
}

public static String decrypt(String str, String Key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException, BadPaddingException {
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(Key.getBytes("UTF8"), "DES");
    dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] dec = BASE64DecoderStream.decode(str.getBytes());
    byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);
    return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
}
```

Console Return :

```
run:
Encryped String : EB6uhzsBl08=
Key : �g�uX8p
Sep 07, 2014 6:35:17 PM Software.Software main
SEVERE: null
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key length: 12 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineGetKeySize(DESCipher.java:373)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.passCryptoPermCheck(Cipher.java:1062)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1020)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:796)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:859)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1229)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1166)
    at Software.Encryption.decrypt(Encryption.java:51)
    at Software.Software.main(main.java:30)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Random bytes from encryption keys are not valid UTF8.  You need base64.

Comment: @SLaks Is there a way to convert base64 to utf8 and back to base64 again?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encode the key in base64

```
public static String[] encrypt(String str) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
        UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException {
    String Key, res;
    SecretKey key;
    String[] Return = new String[2];

    key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
    ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");
    byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

    enc = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(enc);
    res = new String(enc);

    // Returning values 0 = Encrypted String 1 = Key For Storage in XML
    Return[0] = res;
    byte[] keyBytes = key.getEncoded();
    Key = new String(BASE64EncoderStream.encode(keyBytes), "UTF8");
    Return[1] = Key;

    return Return;
}

public static String decrypt(String str, String Key)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
        UnsupportedEncodingException, BadPaddingException {
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(BASE64DecoderStream.decode(Key.getBytes("UTF8")), "DES");
    dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] dec = BASE64DecoderStream.decode(str.getBytes());
    byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);
    return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
}
```